# On mouseenter target a single item

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
<li class="list-group-item"
(mouseenter)="mouseEnter()"
(mouseleave)="mouseLeave()"
(click)="onItemClick($event)">{{ item.expire }}
<span *ngIf="toggle">
    <label (click)="onDelItem()"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></label> 
</span></li>
```

I have a list of items and I want the display to delete icon to the Mouse Enter li(`current li`) items by default that delete icon will be hidden.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to delete dafault icons right?

Comment: Use css to archive this easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of easiest way :-  Try this

```
    <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
    <li class="list-group-item"
    (mouseenter)="item.toggle = true"
    (mouseleave)="item.toggle = false"
    (click)="onItemClick($event)">{{ item.expire }}
    <span *ngIf="item.toggle">
      <label (click)="onDelItem()"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></label> 
    </span>
   </li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using CSS only (disaply the delete icon if the mouse is on the item),

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
   <li class="list-group-item"
       (mouseenter)="mouseEnter()"
       (mouseleave)="mouseLeave()"
       (click)="onItemClick($event)">{{ item.expire }} 
       <label class="delete-icon" (click)="onDelItem()">
             <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
       </label> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

in CSS:

```
.delete-icon {
   display: none;
}


.list-group-item:hover .delete-icon {
   display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can create a runnable snippet.

Comment: it contains Angular syntax, does the "running snippet" can handle it?

Comment: It can but that will be an overkill as you will have to go through to create controller and variables

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following**

**I tried Angular JS first time so so please try to undersrand and Let me know its working or not**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.mouseenter=function($event)
    {
       var SpanEle=angular.element('<span class="CrossSpan")"><i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:red"></i></span>');
     $event.target.append(SpanEle[0]);
    }
    $scope.mouseleave=function($leave)
    {
       angular.element(document.querySelector('.CrossSpan')).remove();
    }
    $scope.SpanClick=function()
    {
    debugger;
       alert('click');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul>
<li ng-mouseenter="mouseenter($event)" ng-mouseleave="mouseleave($leave)">First</li>
<li ng-mouseenter="mouseenter($event)" ng-mouseleave="mouseleave($leave)">Second</li>
<li ng-mouseenter="mouseenter($event)" ng-mouseleave="mouseleave($leave)">Third</li>
<li ng-mouseenter="mouseenter($event)" ng-mouseleave="mouseleave($leave)">Fourth</li>
<li ng-mouseenter="mouseenter($event)" ng-mouseleave="mouseleave($leave)">Fifth</li>
<li ng-mouseenter="mouseenter($event)" ng-mouseleave="mouseleave($leave)">Sixth</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try Following Using jquery**

**You can see Cross on Hover & Can Perform Action on Cross click**

```js
//For showing Cross on Hover
$("li").hover(function(){
        $(this).append('<span class="CrossSpan"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></span>');
        }, function(){
        $(".CrossSpan").remove();
    });
    //For Click Event
    $("li").click(function(){
       alert('Cross Clicked');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
<li>Forth</li>
<li>Fifth</li>
<li>Sixth</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want to achieve but with Angular

Comment: You have giver a tag of Jquery That's why I have given Answer in Jquery

Answer (score -2):

You should use CSS for such requirements. Handling events can get messy.

Following is a sample of an element being shown on hover:

```css
li > span {
  display: none;
}

li:hover > span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li class='myCustomLI'>
  <label class='myCustomLI-label'>Dummy Label</label>
  <span class='myCustomLI-deleteIcon'>Test</span>
</li>

<li class='myCustomLI'>
  <label class='myCustomLI-label'>Dummy Label</label>
  <span class='myCustomLI-deleteIcon'>Test</span>
</li>

<li class='myCustomLI'>
  <label class='myCustomLI-label'>Dummy Label</label>
  <span class='myCustomLI-deleteIcon'>Test</span>
</li>
```

**Note:** I know original question is based on Angular JS, but the requirement is not dependent of Angular and can be achieved using just CSS. This is what above answer depicts. If there is anything incorrect/inappropriate, please comment it along with your vote. A silent vote does not help anyone.

Comment: Your answer is general what if he is using list in his project more than one place? It will create problems for him

Comment: This is a simple depiction. Not a copy-paste solution. OP will have to use more specific selectors. Still, I'll update my snippet if its confusion

Comment: That will be good. Because it can create another problem for him.

Comment: Hi, Rajesh, I have updated the question. My intention is to display the "delete icon" on the item in which the mouse pointing at. Now if I point the mouse on any item, all of the items will display the "delete icon" next to them.

Comment: @Ahmed Since you are giving selector as `lil:hover >` only the element that has been hovered will be affected. I have updated the answer. Kindly check.